# Remove colorbar from map plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray, colorbar, cartopy

I have a plot of a map containing areas which are color coded. I need to remove the automatic color bar from the plot and replace with a legend. However, I cannot find a way to remove the color bar. Xarray was used to create the data array.

```
map_crs = ccrs.OSGB()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 15))
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colours)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bins, ncolors=len(cmap.colors)-1 )
stamen_terrain = cigmt.Stamen('terrain')
ax = plt.axes(projection=stamen_terrain.crs)

data_array.plot(transform=map_crs, vmin=0, vmax=np.max(data_array), cmap=cmap)

plt.gca().coastlines()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(plotname, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.1)
plt.clf()
```

I have tried adding commands such as, `colorbar=False`, `cbar=False`, `Colorbar=False`. However, just continually receive the corresponding error;

```
AttributeError: 'QuadMesh' object has no property 'Colorbar'
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of the colorbar?

Answer (score 1):

Done!

Just needed to put `add_colorbar=False` into the plotting command.

Now to add the legend!